# How can I add data from DataTable to database table directly?

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, dataset

**How can I add data from a DataTable to a database table directly?**

I have searched on the internet not being able to get information from any site.

I have a DataTable and now I want to add that data to a database table.

```
 importData.Tables[1];
 for(int r = 0; r< totalrecoreds; r++;)
 {
         Array test[] =  importData.Tables[1].Rows[r].ItemArray.ToArray;
 }
```

What can I do? Do I have to add data one by one using for loop or is there any other method?

Comment: How does your code relate to your question?

Comment: i have to write for loop to add data to database or what ?

Comment: Please consider giving more specific information about what DBMS you are using, what is behind `importData` etc. Short answer is No, you certainly have different ways to avoid looping like that using an ORM, Linq, and other options

Answer (score 3):

Provided that the schema of the DataTable is the same as the schema of the database table you can just [use a DataAdapter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/33y2221y%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to insert the data.

```
using(var connection = new SqlConnection(...))
using(var adapter = new SqlDataAdapter("SELECT * FROM TABLENAME", connection))
using(var builder = new SqlCommandBuilder(adapter))
{
    adapter.UpdateCommand = builder.GetUpdateCommand();
    adapter.InsertCommand = builder.GetInsertCommand();
    adapter.DeleteCommand = builder.GetDeleteCommand();

    adapter.Update(importData.Tables[1]);
}
```

If the schemas differ you have to add mappings to the DataAdapter, like [the MSDN DataAdapter example](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/33y2221y%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) illustrates.