# Can I add this data from datagridview to database

Tags: c#, database, datagridview

I'm here to ask you one thing.

Can I add this data from datagridview to database with `consumidor final` id, clicking at `Confirmar` button?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Provided that the schema of the DataTable is the same as the schema of the database table you can just use a DataAdapter to insert the data.
Have a look here: [How can I add data from DataTable to database table directly?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9326622/how-can-i-add-data-from-datatable-to-database-table-directly)
Stuart

Answer (score 0):

As you can try this:

```
SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(ConnString))
SqlCommand sqlCommand = new SqlCommand()
sqlCommand.Connection = sqlConnection;
sqlConnection.Open();

for(int i=0; i< myDataGridView.Rows.Count;i++)
{
       query= @"INSERT INTO tableName VALUES (" 
              + ddlConsumidorFinalId.SelectedValue + ", "
              + myDataGridView.Rows[i].Cells["ColumnName"].Value +", " 
              + myDataGridView.Rows[i].Cells["ColumnName"].Value +");";
                    //Add as pre table fields
              sqlCommand.CommandText = query;
              sqlCommand.ExecuteNonQuery();
}
```

For more, [See this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10556556/insert-all-data-of-a-datagridview-to-database-at-once).